# Array does not show all elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code from my program. As you see I get all pixel of Image in matrix.
In this code I receive Height and Weight and successfully calculate total pixels in an image.

```
public static void GetMatrix(File input) {
       File file = input;
    try {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int[][] matricesA = new int[image.getWidth(null)][image.getHeight(null)];
        System.out.println("Total Pixel : " + image.getWidth(null) * image.getHeight(null));
      System.out.println(fProjectionH(matricesA));   
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MatrixCompare.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When it comes to calculate **Horizontal projection** I recieve not all elements of array (only square matrix, for example, [120]*[120]), but Image actually consists [210][120]
Here is the code of finding projection

```
public static int fProjectionH(int[][] a) throws IOException
{   
    int err = 0;
       for(int j=0; j < a[j].length; j++){
            for(int i=0; i < a[i].length; i++){
                     int alt = a[j].length;
                     int[] proj = new int[alt]; 
                 if(a[j][i] == 255) {proj[j] += 1;}
                 System.out.println("a["+j+"]"+"["+i+"]="+proj[j]);   
           }     
        }      
       return err;
   }
```

How I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

UPD 1: I already try a lot things.

```
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < a[j].length; j++){
```

UPD 2: Forgot to mention, that I post array to function via 
     *System.out.println(**fProjectionH**(matricesA));*

UPD 3:

```
private static void handlepixels(Image img, int x, int y, int w, int h, int[][] matrices) {
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, x, y, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    try {
        pg.grabPixels();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("interrupted waiting for pixels!");
        return;
    }
    if ((pg.getStatus() & ImageObserver.ABORT) != 0) {
        System.err.println("image fetch aborted or errored");
        return;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            matrices[i][j] = handlesinglepixel(x + i, y + j, pixels[j * w + i]);
        }
    }
}
```

UPD 4: I uploaded on GitHub [link]https://github.com/aydin1918/test

Comment: Are you sure that matricesA is 210x120? Can you test that before you pass the array to the fProjectionH method?

Comment: @blahfunk, Yes, it is 210x120. Because the Image has the size 210x120. And I got the total number of pixels - 25200 (my java program outputs)

Comment: what is the value of `a[j].length();`?

Comment: @blahfunk  - the value of a[j].length() - 120

Comment: @blahfunk, In additional, the value of  "a.length" - is 210 and "a[i].length" - 120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your for loop to this:

```
   for(int j=0; j < a.length; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < a[j].length; i++){
             //do stuff  
       }     
    }
```

Your outer loop was only looping to `120` because you were only looping to `a[j].length` which is `120`. You want to loop to `a.length` which is `210`. Hope this helps.

Example:

```
int[][] a = new int[210][120];
int count = 0;
for(int j=0; j < a.length; j++){
    for(int i=0; i < a[j].length; i++){
        count++;
   }     
} 
System.out.println(count);
```

Output:

```
25200
```

Comment: Thanks @gonzo, but I again got the same result

Comment: @Aydin are you sure? I just tried it and I got every single element? I'll add the test code I'm using.

Comment: @Aydin What does `System.out.println(image.getWidth(null));` and `System.out.println(image.getHeight(null));` print?  Please print them separate and do not multiply.

Comment: It print a number of pixels in the Image. You find total amount through the loops, but I get the Height and Width of Image and then multiplied.

Comment: @Aydin I understand that. Can you still print them and post that to the question. We can not analyze the problems further if we do not know what those methods return.

Comment: I delete this "  System.out.println(image.getWidth(null)); and System.out.println(image.getHeight(null));  "... But again got the same result

Comment: @Aydin no I am not saying to delete them. I'm just saying print them out to the console and show us the result. But separate and not multiplied.

Comment: @Aydin you are calling another method, `handlepixels`, that you have not showed us...  That is probably where your `a` is changing.  Comment that out for now but still call `fProjectionH`. It should print everything. Also can you show us what is in `handlepixels`?

Comment: Please see the UPD 3. Now I comment the handlepixels method and all my Horizontal projection stand at value - 0. But, anyway, the matrix again show the square matrix (119x119)

Comment: @Aydin and you kept the change of `fProjectionH` with the solution I provided correct? And it still printed 119x119?

Comment: Please see my GitHub. You can find the link on UPD 4.

Comment: @Aydin change you inner for loop to `for(int i=0; i < a[j].length; i++)`

Comment: It did not help. But I change the "int alt = a[j].length" to "int alt = a.length;" and It shows the whole array!. Please make some edit in your answer. Thank you!